# looking to find version 0.6.0 of KaboomJS

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I'm wondering if someone can help me find version **0.6.0 of KaboomJS.**
i looked for the kaboom files for awhile now and i could not find this specific version

Answer (score -1):

You could try using npm:

```js
npm install kaboom@version
```

(replacing version with the desired version)

According to the docs, you'll also need to bundle it to use it: https://kaboomjs.com/doc/setup

Or you could look for the version you want on their releases page: https://github.com/replit/kaboom/tags

However, I can't seem to find version 0.6.0 anywhere. Are you looking for v2000.0.0 instead?